# Rails 3.2: Checking if a namespaced model is loadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a gemified engine, this engine has a function that will use const_get from file names to fill in some database basic stuff.
Please note that I am still really new to rails.
What I want is for the engine to test if the constant exists first and if not turn the first object in the underscore case into a namespace rather than part of the constant name.
Now `defined?` won't work here because these are all 'in load path' stuff, so if they haven't been loaded yet they won't be recognized - on this point I understand there are some differences between the way the development and the production environments work and I don't entirely understand the difference nor could I find thorough documentation of the difference so if I could be pointed at something or given a brief explanation of what happens that would be amazing!
So basically what I want is to have something working in the style of:

```
def get_namespaced_class(underscored_name)
...
end

get_namespaced_call('mygem_some_class') #returns Mygem::SomeClass class
```

The way I see it, the method would first check if `MygemSomeClass` is reachable and then start checking namespace options.
One thing I really want to avoid is catching the `NameError` I see that as just dirty and wrong, I want to look up what I have that I can reach, there should be a way to do so I believe because rails seems to be doing it itself.

Comment: The way Rails uses Ruby's autoload you might not be able to get around rescuing NameError, as wrong as it feels.

Comment: If that's the case it might take me a day or two just to digest the fact that I have to go through that. Is there's a way to, say load all my main apps and gems models on startup rather than at first call I might be able to work with that too.

Comment: I think you can use config.threadsafe! http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html

Comment: So this works for most cases, I simply use `preload_framework = true` but then in the very specific scenario of `rake db:seed` or any other rake command, even though it depends of `:environment` the constants don't seem to be there